# How to read key values from a property file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to read properties from a config file - in a key value pair format from my main.js

I have a config file config.json

```
{
 "IGUrl": "xyz",
 "Key": "abc",
 "dbName": "node-login"
}
```

I want to read the property say "IGUrl" from my app.js.

The code to access and read this file is

```
    var config  = require('./config.json');
    var x = config.IGUrl;
    console.log("TEST URL " + x)
```

But this is giving me an error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'IGUrl' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse after require the file?

Comment: `var { config } = require('./config.json')` you are not importing correctly. If you would import correctly it will work. In config file you need `module.exports = objectThatYouAreExporting`

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was the `JSON.parse()` as well, but just tested this on my node and apparently requiring a json file automatically parses it. So your posted code works for me. Which version of node.js are you running since iirc, requiring a json file is a relatively recent addition.

Comment: The user is importing a JSON file, no a JS module in some kind of module format. So exporting should not matter. And it seems requiring a json file has been in node since 0.5. I just copy pasted the OP code and everything works for me as expected on node v12.2.0 . Are you running this on the client? Or with a non-node version of `require()` ?

Comment: What version of Nodejs are you using @psd and is `config.json` in same directory as `main.js`

Comment: you dont need json.parse for a json file, you dont module exports for a json file, post your project structure, you're probably requiring the wrong path or you're running from an npm script and need to resolve the path with `cwd` or something

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a common `JS` file instead. Is much easier and there is no need to do anything special other than accessing the file.

```
export const properties = {
    IGUrl: "xyz",
    Key: "abc",
    dbName: "node-login"
};

export default properties;
```

Then whenever you need to access it, just use the following code.

```
import properties from './path/properties';

console.log(properties.IGUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is on client side, the require statement wouldn't work.
I just had to have the config file in my html file and reference it directly in my main.js

config.js

```
const properties = {
    url: "xyz",
    key: "abc",
    dbName: "node-login"
    };
```

main.js

```
console.log("TEST " + properties.url);
```

index.html

```
<script src="/config.js"></script>
```